# How can Change the port number of connection programmatically -Android

Tags: php, android, proxy, wamp, wampserver

In WAMP server the port number was changed to 81 instead of 80 (to be able for another app to run). However, when I attempt to connect to server in which WAMP port number changed, to get data from data base,  just my app stopped!  I want to set the port-number for  connection programmatically. I attempt to do such things which are:

- change the proxy setting manually from phone setting  itself (which succeeded with me). But, what I am looking for to be able to do that programmatically.
- attempt to append Android Proxy Library. (which does not succeed with me) just many errors !
- attempt to append the prot number with connection call statement, but
  also this does not work. The call statement is:

  ```
  try {
      result=bringData("http://"+IpAddress+"/android_connect/test.php",dbname,dbpass);

  } catch (Exception e) {    
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();

  }
  ```

But when I append port number to IpAddress this does not work also, as for example:

```
    try {
        result=bringData("http://192.168.0.20:81/android_connect/test.php",dbname,dbpass);

    } catch (Exception e) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

The **code** that connect to data-base:

```
    public String  bringData(String url, String jsonValue1, String jsonValue2) throws JSONException { 
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("dbname",jsonValue1);
        json.put("dbpass", jsonValue2);

         JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
         postjson.put(json);

         // Post the data:
         httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
         httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

         // Execute HTTP Post Request
         System.out.print(json);
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

         // for JSON:
         if(response != null) {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                        int count=0;
                         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             result=line; 
                         }

                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                         try {
                             is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   }
              }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return result; //returned results from php code 

    }
```

**In sum**, If there are any ideas or solutions or source code that can use to change the port number of connection for Android app. please?

Thanks In advance.